# Instrument Energy consumption in iOS8.4.1

Tags: ios, energy, consumption

I am using iOS 8.4.1 and currently looking to measure energy (power) consumption for one of the apps using instrumentation "Energy consumption".

I followed some tutorials and found that there are some statistics been spit out such as "Energy Usage Level". They came out as 1/20 to 20/20.

Question is how do we quantify the energy consumption for the particular app? How do we define the measurement level in this case?

Note: I am aware there are some questions in the past along this thread but it was a couple of years ago. I thought maybe there are some new insights with respect to the latest iOS 8.4 or even iOS 9.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find an answer to identify the energy use of specific apps?